# How to create a likes and comment system in PostgreSQL?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

**Context:** I'm in an apprenticeship at Openclassrooms.com (Web dev path), and I'm doing the last project: I have to create a social network website from scratch, for the front-end I must use a framework of my choice (Vue.js, React, Angular, Svelte...) and for the back-end I must use an SQL database (like MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQLite...).

For the Front-end, I'm using Angular.

For the Back-end, I'm using Node.js + Express + Sequelize

For the Database, I chose PostgreSQL

I did almost all the routes for the signup, login, view all posts and do CRUD operations with a single post.

But I'm stuck with the post controller for the likes and comments.

In the previous project of my apprenticeship, I had to create the Back-end where I had to do *almost* the same thing the posts were without comments), at the exception that I used Mongoose to make CRUD operations in MongoDB

The user had this model:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const sauceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  manufacturer: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  mainPepper: { type: String, required: true },
  imageUrl: { type: String, required: true },
  heat: { type: Number, required: true, minimum: 1, maximum: 10 },
  likes: { type: Number, required: true },
  dislikes: { type: Number, required: true },
  usersLiked: { type: Array, required: true },
  usersDisliked: { type: Array, required: true },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Sauce", sauceSchema);
```

So here's how the likes for the previous project with `MongoDB + Mongoose` worked:

When the user liked a post, the front-end would send the userId (string) of the person who liked + like (integer between -1 and 1) + post_id (string) to the back-end

We search for the post in the database, and if it's present in the database, then we'll manipulate the likes/dislikes

Switch **case 1:** the like = 1/-1 → is the like/dislike present in the array of usersLiked/usersDisliked?

If it is → we remove the userId from the usersLiked/usersDisliked
If not → we add the userId in the usersLiked/usersDisliked array

And the amount of likes/dislikes is the length of the array

**case 2**: the like = 0 (meaning the user removes the like/dislike of the post) → Is the userId present in the usersLiked array?

If it is → we remove the userId from the usersLiked
If not → we remove the userId from the usersDisiked

Here's the code btw:

```js
const findIndexInArray = require("../utils/likeSauce-function");

exports.likeSauce = (req, res, next) => {
    Sauce.findOne({
            _id: req.params.id,
        })
        .then((sauce) => {
            let userId = req.body.userId;
            let numberOfLikes = sauce.likes;
            let numberOfDislikes = sauce.dislikes;
            let usersLikedArray = sauce.usersLiked;
            let usersDislikedArray = sauce.usersDisliked;

            let userLikedOrDisliked = req.body.like;
            console.log("Valeur de likes dans B2D: ", userLikedOrDisliked);
            switch (userLikedOrDisliked) {
                case 1:
                    {
                        //Où on like
                        let indexFound = findIndexInArray(usersLikedArray, userId);
                        if (indexFound > -1) {
                            console.log(
                                "User ID: " +
                                userId +
                                " found in the usersLikedArray → Like cancelled"
                            );
                            usersLikedArray.splice(indexFound, 1);
                        } else {
                            console.log(
                                "User ID: " +
                                userId +
                                " has NOT been found in the array of userIDs → Like added"
                            );
                            usersLikedArray.push(userId);
                        }
                        numberOfLikes = usersLikedArray.length;
                        let sauceObject = {
                            ...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sauce)),
                            usersLiked: usersLikedArray,
                            likes: numberOfLikes,
                        };
                        Sauce.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, {...sauceObject, _id: req.params.id })
                        .then(() =>
                            res
                            .status(200)
                            .json({ message: "Sauce Object SUCCESSFULLY modified !" })
                        )
                        .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({ error }));
                        break;
                    }

                    //
                case -1:
                    {
                        //Où on like
                        let indexFound = findIndexInArray(usersDislikedArray, userId);
                        if (indexFound > -1) {
                            console.log(
                                "User ID: " +
                                userId +
                                " found in the usersLikedArray → Like cancelled"
                            );
                            usersDislikedArray.splice(indexFound, 1);
                        } else {
                            console.log(
                                "User ID: " +
                                userId +
                                " has NOT been found in the array of userIDs → Like added"
                            );
                            usersDislikedArray.push(userId);
                        }
                        numberOfDislikes = usersDislikedArray.length;
                        let sauceObject = {
                            ...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sauce)),
                            usersDisliked: usersDislikedArray,
                            dislikes: numberOfDislikes,
                        };
                        Sauce.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, {...sauceObject, _id: req.params.id })
                        .then(() =>
                            res
                            .status(200)
                            .json({ message: "Sauce Object SUCCESSFULLY modified !" })
                        )
                        .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({ error }));
                        break;
                    }

                case 0:
                    {
                        let index = findIndexInArray(usersLikedArray, userId);
                        if (index > -1) {
                            usersLikedArray.splice(index, 1);
                            numberOfLikes = usersLikedArray.length;
                            let sauceObject = {
                                ...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sauce)),
                                usersLiked: usersLikedArray,
                                likes: numberOfLikes,
                            };
                            Sauce.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, {...sauceObject, _id: req.params.id })
                                .then(() =>
                                    res.status(200).json({
                                        message: "Sauce Object SUCCESSFULLY liked !",
                                    })
                                )
                                .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({ error }));
                        } else {
                            index = findIndexInArray(usersDislikedArray, userId);
                            if (index > -1) {
                                usersDislikedArray.splice(index, 1);
                                numberOfDislikes = usersDislikedArray.length;
                                let sauceObject = {
                                    ...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sauce)),
                                    usersDisliked: usersDislikedArray,
                                    dislikes: numberOfDislikes,
                                };
                                Sauce.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, {...sauceObject, _id: req.params.id })
                                    .then(() =>
                                        res.status(200).json({
                                            message: "Sauce Object SUCCESSFULLY disliked !",
                                        })
                                    )
                                    .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({ error }));
                            }
                        }

                        break;
                    }

                default: //Pas de likes/dislikes AJOUTÉS par défaut
                    break;
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error while attempting to find the sauce: " + error);
            res.status(404).json({ error });
        });
};
```

So that's the algorithm with the likes/dislikes of a post with `MongoDB + Mongoose`,
It's a rather simple implementation...

But how do I implement the like/dislike feature with `PostgreSQL + Sequelize`?

At first, I thought that I had to add a likes attribute to the table `post`, but that's wrong, I actually had to create a table for the likes and comments

So for the likes table:

1. -1 like_id attribute as the primary key
2. -2 other attributes as foreign keys (user_id and post_id)

For the comments table:

1. -1 comment_id attribute as the primary key
2. -3 other attributes as foreign keys (user_id, post_id and like_id)

Here also are the Sequelize models for each feature:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Like = sequelize.define("like", {
        like_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        user_id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            //   references: "user", //Nom de notre table
            //   referencesKey: "user_id", //L'attribut référencé de la PK ce cette table
        },
        post_id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            //   references: "post", //Nom de notre table
            //   referencesKey: "post_id", //L'attribut référencé de la PK ce cette table
        },
    });
    return Like;
};


module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Comment = sequelize.define("comment", {
        comment_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        user_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: "user", 
            referencesKey: "user_id", 
        },
        post_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: "post", 
            referencesKey: "post_id", 
        },
        likes_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: "likes", //Nom de notre table
            referencesKey: "likes_id", 
        },
    });
    return Comment;
};
```

For the controller, I just have *no idea as to how to do it*, I looked at some posts but nothing very satisfying, if anyone could enlighten me, even just by giving me a hint, I'd be very grateful.

Also, here's an Entity Relationship Diagram to show all the tables I created:
[image: Entity Relationship Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

I try this with mongoose but i hope with sequelize you can adjust to fit your request. I hope this can help you if there's any problem you can fix this comment and let me know.

```
export const commentPost = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        const { comment } = req.body;

        if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) throw new Error(`No post with id: ${id}`);

        const post = await PostMessage.findById(id);

        if (!post) throw new Error(`No post found with id: ${id}`);

        post.comments.push({ text: comment });
        const updatedPost = await post.save();

        res.json(updatedPost);

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).send(err.message);
    }
}
```